# How to release app that replaces several old apps for all users?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am developing several apps for AppStore, with different bundle IDs, but similar logic. Now I am working on a new concept, which covers all the logic from those apps into one common project. Hence, I would like to prepare a new app, that is intended to replace all the old apps. How can I ensure that? 
To be clear, I want all the users to install the new app, run it, so that it can transfer data and functionality from old apps installed on user's device. How can I do that, so that all data and functionality will be kept depending on which old apps had each user installed, and Apple will be OK with such a change and behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you will have to replace all the old apps with new once. You can't update the app bundle ID in a new version.